# No push certificate in p12 file?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to use a push notification debugging tool and found that it requires a certificate to be imported. I exported my enterprise profile's p12 file. In Xcode, I can see that Push notifications are enabled under this enterprise profile. However, when I import into this debugger tool, I am facing this issue of no push certificates found. Is this "push certificate" different from a distribution certificate that has push notifications enabled?

[image: APNS cert error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the certificate you are referring to is the signing certificate for the app.

There is a separate Push Notification certificate that can be created that I think Pusher wants you to upload. 
[You create these by going to your developer account and Create New Certficate from there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdNFb.png)

There is a new way of adding Push Notifications to apps now using a Key rather than these certificates, if you are using this method, you might have to find a tool that can support that.